# Handling large data in Java Web Application

Tags: javascript, java, html

I have been assigned with a task to handle large number of data and show then to a webpage tabular form. I'm using HTML/JSP and JS for Frontend and Java as backend.
Business logic is to query database (for me it's Oracle) and get data.
Query looks something like
Select field1, field2 etc.. from table where field1 = "SearchString"
Limit 30

The search string will be given by user.

So, each time the query gets executed I'm getting 30 rows and storing it in a bean.
And with field2 data from iteration 1 I'll execute the query again which will give another 30 rows, I will append those in the bean and loop continues untill there is no matching records. After that I need to display the bean data in UI in tabular form.

Now problem arises when the data is huge. Like, the iteration goes on 1000 times giving 30k records. Then the code is getting stuck in this loop for more time and UI screen is showing loading.

Is there a better approach to my situation?

Note : I can't do any operation the query. Because it's forbidden.
And the query is pseudo query not actual. If the first record has matching record of 30k rows. I need to take 30 in each iteration.

Comment: why are you doing the looping again and again. I mean if you want to search your string in all fields, you can use query like 'Select field1, field2 from table where field1 like '%searchString%' or field2 like '%searchString%' limit 30.

Comment: I can't change the query because it's forbidden from business.

Comment: So basically @AvinashSagar is right, they way how you query data from db is kinda strange. You didnt specify, how the data is returned to client. Is this direct response of incoming query of the user? Anyway, if you have collected all items, the client should ideally only request a bunch of data (lets say the first 100 items) and display it. Now if the user scrolls the table down, you would usually fire a new request to server, which loads the next 100 items and use JS to manipulate the DOM (adding new recently items to table)

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments that this is not the best practice when you are trying to present thousands and thousands of rows to the UI...

It really sounds like you should implement pagination on your UI.  This is done by using queries... I don't know what DB system you are using but here is a [guide on pagination](https://www.sqlshack.com/pagination-in-sql-server/) for SQL Server.

You can explain to the business that using pagination is better for the user.  Use the example of how google search gives you pages of search results instead of showing you millions of websites of cat pictures all in one page.